# Geolocation not working at all, can't find a solution don't think there is anything wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to use Geolocation on Google Maps, but when the page loads, nothing happens I have googled many different examples and many different things but I cannot seem to find an answer, I really don't see anything wrong with my code.

```
<script>
var initialLocation;
var map;
var markersArray = [];
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
  }
};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'),
  mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    deleteOverlays();
    addMarker(event.latLng);
    updateTextFields(latitude, longitude);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    showInfo(window);
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    alert('Browser Supports but Im not doing anything yet');
  } else {
    error('Geo Location is not supported');
  }
}

function updateTextFields(lati, longi) {
  $('#inputLatitude').val(lati);
  $('#inputLongitude').val(longi);
}


function addMarker(location) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&' +
  'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 190; // Calculate the top offset

    $('#gmaps').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
  }).resize();
  window.onload = loadScript;
});


</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is because `window.onload` has already been called by time you are in `$(document).ready()`. Try just calling `loadScript()` instead of setting it to `window.onload`.

Comment: What is the html for #gmaps - Are you specifying width and height?

Comment: @GreenGuerilla The map is loading fine, everything loads great, but its just not using geolocation, everything is working as intended minus the geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a function to `window.onload` *after* the window has loaded; thus it won't be called.

The following would be better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 190; // Calculate the top offset

    $('#gmaps').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
  }).resize();
  loadScript();
});
```

In addition:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
```

requires a function called `success` that takes the geolocation position as an input parameter. I don't see such a function in your code.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. But my code still is not working as intended.

Comment: Can you provide a link so that we can take a look at it live?

Comment: Unfortionately it's part or an administration page so I can't but I will provide a screenshot

Comment: There is a screenshot in the main post now, and I replaced the getCurrentPosition line with just alerts to see if its working, but none of the geolocation is working

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'not working'? Not showing anything? Showing incorrect information? Logging an error?

Comment: Also, can you take a look at this http://sscce.org/ and provide an SSCCE on something like jsfiddle?